# Работа с FileFilter

Tags: java

Посмотрите, пожалуйста, может ли в приниципе такой класс работать. Надо показать в файлчузере только файлы xml, содержащие в названии некие символы и ранее не загружившиеся в базу. Первые два условия фильтра нормально работали сами по себе, но когда понадобилось прикрутить резалтсет метод стал ругаться про потеряный return

```
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;

public class XmlFilesFilter extends FileFilter {

    private String file_name;//принимает нужное начало файла
    private String extension;//принимает расширение
    private ResultSet rs_file_exists;//уже загруженные в базу файлы

    public XmlFilesFilter(String file_name,
            String extension,
            ResultSet rs_file_exists) {
        this.file_name = file_name;
        this.extension = extension;
        this.rs_file_exists = rs_file_exists;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            return true;}
        try {
            while (rs_file_exists.next()) {
                if (file.getName().toUpperCase().startsWith(rs_file_exists.getString("FILE_NAME"))
                 ||!file.getName().toUpperCase().startsWith(file_name)
                 ||!file.getName().toUpperCase().endsWith(extension)) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
    }}} catch (Exception f) {
            f.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Он ругается про потерянный return потому что не понятно, что вернуть, если мы прошли по циклу и всё закончилось. Если бы вы форматировали нормально код, то вопрос про return не возникал бы.

Но дело не в этом. А в том, что выполнять запросы к БД в UI-потоке - преступление, за которое надо отстреливать немедленно. Серебрянными пулями, протёртыми чесноком.

**UPD**

Не говоря уже о том, что метод accept вызывается много раз, а resultset у вас похоже один.. так что он сработает один раз для одного файла, а потом все файлы будут считаться доступными.

Вообще, формат диалога открытия файлов плохо подходит для такого рода фильтров. Кроме того, это противоречит user experience: пользователи привыкли, что фильтр файлов в диалоге открытия файлов связан с типом файла, а не с его доступностью на открытие. Более того, человека может сильно испугать, что файлы "пропадают" по мере их выбора. Более того, сильный тормоза при смене папок будут раздражать пользователя ещё сильнее, так как диалог выбора файлов должен работать быстро, а не тормозить и делать бог знает что на каждый чих-пых.

Но если очень уж сильно хочется, то и технически это некрасиво: нужна запускать фоновую задачу по фильтрации файлов, а в UI похоже придётся делать блокировку с таймаутом с ожиданием выполнения задачи. Кроме того, делать запрос на каждый файл не хорошая идея, так как время выполнения пропорционально количеству файлов в директории, так что если пользователь случайно зайдёт в какую-нибудь системную директорию, то он может зависнуть и, к тому же, положить базу просто напросто.

Лично я бы не стал делать это в фильтре вообще. Я бы сделал в диалоге просто фильтр на тип файла (xml), а проверку по базе делал уже когда пользователь выберет файл(ы) и нажмёт открыть. После этого можно отсеять уже выгруженные файлы и сделать пользователю замечание, если файл(ы) уже там.

Второй вариант, это сделать свой диалог выбора (возможно на базе существующего), который бы показывал иконку загрузки, если файлов много. Хотя это всё равно не решает проблему громадного количества запросов к базе. Так что, остаётся вариант 1.

Comment: Спасибо. Я знаю, что ТАК делать не надо. Но, к сожалению, пока не знаю КАК надо.

Comment: На продолжение ответа: про попадание пользователя в директорию с большим кол-вом файлов я конечно не подумал. Спасибо за советы, фильтр оставлю как был, проверку уникальности повешу на базу.
...
А может стоит дропать файлы по мере их обработки? Они одноразовые - залил в БД и не нужны..

Comment: Если вы повесите проверку уникальности на базу, то вы не сможете сообщать что-то адекватное пользователю. У вас будет получаться либо неизвестная SQL-ошибка, либо молчок. Но проверка уникальности тоже не помешает: зачем нам там дубликаты? По поводу удаление файлов по мере обработки: я бы не делал этого по умолчанию, но сделал бы где-нибудь галочку типа "удалить файл(ы) после отправки".

Comment: а еще лучше по умолчанию перемещать их в папку с для обработанных файлов. а вот галочку "удалить после отправки" стоит оставить :)

Answer (score 1):

можно переписать код и сделать что-нить такое:

```
import java.io.File ;
import java.sql.Connection ;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement ;
import java.sql.ResultSet ;
import java.sql.SQLException ;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter ;

public class XmlFilesFilter extends FileFilter
{
    private final DBUtil dbutil = null ;

    // ... all other declarations

    @Override
    public boolean accept ( final File file )
    {
        // do accept directories
        if ( file.isDirectory () )
        {
            return true ;
        }

        // accept only non-processed files
        try
        {
            return !dbutil.isFileProcessed ( file.getName () ) ;
        }
        catch ( final SQLException e )
        {
            // we can't do much more here
            // just ignore this file
        }

        // by default do not accept files
        return false ;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription ()
    {
        // TODO: fix file descriptions
        return null ;
    }
}

class DBUtil
{
    private final Connection connection = null ;

    public boolean isFileProcessed ( final String filename ) throws SQLException
    {
        // prepare statement
        final String sql = "Select count(*) from PROCESSED_FILES where lower(file_name) like '?%.xml'" ;
        final PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement ( sql ) ;

        // set query parameters
        statement.setString ( 1, filename.toLowerCase () ) ;

        // execute query
        final ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery () ;

        // do check if we have any records in output
        if ( !resultset.next () )
        {
            return false ;
        }

        // get result
        final int count = resultset.getInt ( 1 ) ;

        // file not found, - it is not processed
        return (0 == count) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Это всё равно будет плохо в силу всего вышесказанного. Кроме того, что будет, если в процессе обработки связь с базой временно пропадёт, а потом вернётся? Получится, что некоторые, возможно, валидные файлы будут невидимы, в то время как должны быть. Это введение пользователя в заблуждение. А это самое плохое, что может случиться. Уж лучше совсем всё закиснет с ошибкой, чем будет отображено заведомое враньё.

Comment: согласен. более правильно было бы в filechooser принимать все xml файлы и уже после выбора проверять на то обработаны они или нет. если обработан то предлагать выбрать другой файл "open" и "cancel" - чтоб выйти. но это не мне решать.   
практически этот код делает тоже самое, но более читабельный и более оптимально работает с БД + разделение функционала по классам  

я не пытаюсь решить проблему за автора, я пытаюсь помочь ему :)